# node.js works but npm --version responds with "The syntax of the command is incorrect"

Tags: node.js, npm

I am running windows 10.
Installed node.js from node site.

After install node --version works

npm --version responds with "The syntax of the command is incorrect".

Cannot find anything about how to fix.
Anybody have any ideas?

I went through and uninstalled all the npm versions and node I could find

Comment: What terminal do you use?